# RUN-TIME ERROR 3633 CAN'T LOAD DLL:MSJTER35.DLL

Tags: vb6

I have an application that runs on standard computers, however when I try to run the application through citrix this error message occurs.

RUN-TIME ERROR 3633 CAN'T LOAD DLL:MSJTER35.DLL

the problem is in my application or Citrix?